# Intel VTune Amplifier XE 2013 modules of interest

Tags: intel-vtune, aqtime

I'm a beginner in VTune. But I have some experience in AQTime 8. Now I'm using Intel VTune Amplifier XE 2013. In my opinion, it has many advantages over AQTime. There is a interesting question.
In AQtime I can choose modules of my interest to profile them. It's very useful, because I have to profile only one dll from the big project. Is there such a possibility in Intel VTune Amplifier XE 2013?

I have tried to find an answer, but found only this ([Is it possible to use vtune on certain code snippets in a binary and not an entire binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750297/is-it-possible-to-use-vtune-on-certain-code-snippets-in-a-binary-and-not-an-enti)).

Please advice me

Comment: VTune does not instrument modules in order to collect data so there is no big value to specify module of interest in VTune case. VTune will however spend some time to extract function/source file information from all modules which have performance information. This will happen after collection and does not affect application runtime.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Your answer is very useful. Also I got the same answer here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/comment/1830731#comment-1830731. I think, this information will help someone who is a begginer in VTune too.

Answer (score 0):

VTune Amplifier can limit data collection to a specific process and, optionally, any child processes, but it collects data in all modules of that process.

Then, you use the display options to limit data to the "module of interest".

You can either select a module from the filter bar at the bottom of the Bottom Up view or select the "Module / Function / Call stack" grouping in the same view.

You can use the Pause/Resume APIs to limit data collection to a "region."

It will not limit profiling to a module - any code executed in the process between the __itt_resume() API and the __itt_pause() API will be sampled.

Even though your query is resolved, I am posting this to help others with similar issues. :)